# JPA/Hibernate One To One Extra Columns

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables, PERSON and WORKPLACE, which relationship is one to one.
I need a 3rd table with name PERSON_WORKPLACE where to join the 2 tables mentioned before. 
The structure must be the following:
[image]

That's the code I have now:

PERSON:

```
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String password;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "person_workplace",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "workplace_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private Workplace workplace;
}
```

WORKPLACE:

```
public class Workplace extends Auditable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private int number;
private float coordX;
private float coordY;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Floor floor;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "workplace")
private Person person;
}
```

This way my table PERSON_WORKPLACE just has 2 columns, with the 2 ids from PERSON and WORKPLACE, and need it to be like in the picture. With his own id, the 2 ids and an extra column called date.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be more simple if you create your own class `WorkplacePerson.java` and add the required annotations.

Comment: I've been thinking about it but, I don't really know the relationships I should use with Person and Workplace, should they be one to one aswell in that new class? @GabLeg

Comment: I don't know your domain, put in my opinion, a person could have two place at a time. But if you want to keep `one to one`, you could do it too. There is no difference between what you want to achieve with hibernate and doing it manually/"physically". Instead of self-generating, you just write the code it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use mapping a Join Table with Additional Columns: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I don't really understand that example. Maybe it's too complicated, using a list of project association... I think what I need is easier and is also a one to one relationship, what I suppose is similar

Comment: OneToOne relation is bewteen 2 tables with one FK. According your tables structure it is obviously  ManyToMany. Added another example link, maybe you will understand from it

Comment: It's possible that my tables are wrong then. A person just can work at one workplace at the same time. While the workplace just can be used by one person.